# How to explore a ApacheMQ Queue to view all messages that are sent to it

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have got started with ActiveMQ and able to move forward, but I am not able to figure out how I can view all messages that are sent to a particular queue.

I can see the message in the queue as long as it is not consumed by a consumer but as soon as it is consumed by a consumer, I can no longer see the message in the queue.

In my project I used to use "MQJ Explorer" and connect with a queue manager and there I could view all the messages that were sent to a particular queue, so I am expecting similar thing with ActiveMQ.

I know while sending I can have the message marked as "persistent" but still it will be there in the queue only till it is not consumed, once it is consumed I cannot see it any more.

Please let me know if things work differently with ActiveMQ.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Queue holds messages until they are consumed at which point they are discarded.  So you cannot browse all messages that were sent to the queue and then consumed.  The only solution to this would be to use a Camel route or similar to mirror the Queue to some other Audit type Queue but you'd need to use a lot of care as this could easily lead to filling the message store as the mirrored messages will continue to grow and take space unless they are purged periodically.

Comment: Ok, but then how come in my project I was able to view, I don't know what kind of MOM implementation it was but do you know if it is possible that some implementation like Weblogic MQ provider supports this feature? I mean is this even possible or only way to achieve this is the way you are mentioning?

Comment: I can't speak for other implementations, ActiveMQ doesn't keep a historical view of Queue data.  A message broker is not a database, messages come and go.

Comment: I did bit of more research and I think this is the overall behavior of all MOM implementations that you cannot view dequeued messages, if really required then you can have another queue just for read only purpose.